# Express middleware with nested callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my server controller code i have a method that retrieves an income and an expense object based on a provided id. The code is problematic though, cause if the expense method fails, the `next()` chain of the middleware is broken. What has been done is basically to append Expense.findById part inside the callback of the Income.findById.

Can nested callbacks like this be avoided? note that the expense._id is unknown until the income has been fetched.

```
 /**
     * Transfer middleware
     * Returns an income from id if the income has the 'isTransfer attribute set' and the corresponding expense
     */
    exports.transferByID = function(req, res, next, id) {
      var expense;

      Income.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, income) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (! income) return next(new Error('Failed to load Income ' + id));
            if(income.isTransfer){
              Expense.findById(income.expense).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, expense) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                if (! expense) return next(new Error('Failed to load Expense ' + id));
                if(expense.isTransfer){
                    req.transfer = {income:income, expense:expense};
                    next();
                }
              });

            }else{
              req.transfer={};
              req.transfer.name = "The selected transaction is not a transfer" ;
            }

        //What happens if i get here?
        });
    };
```

**Clarification:** If income succeeds and expense fail will I end up at the comment, for example if the expense has not got isTransfer===true?. But if I put next at the comment the next will fire before the expense has been found.

Comment: Just call `next` in your `else` part after setting `req.transfer`

Comment: Can I just highlight this "What is the proper way to get both income and expense from the mongoose model?". Therefore to begin with "What is the proper way.." is putting the gun to your head and pulling the trigger to say **Primarily Opinion Based** to all of use that review and close vote for questions on that reason. As I have been typing this you moved it from the "bottom" to the "top" of the question which makes it real bad.

Comment: Separate point here is `Income` and `Expense` here as separate models seems to be most of your problem. Take a step back from this. Don't ask "how to fix my code", but describe the problem you are really trying to solve when you wrote the middleware as is. A fresh set of eyes on the original problem often works out well.

Comment: You are correct, in that it probably would be easier to develop one model for "transactions" (both incomes and expenses) and if there is a need to present incomes and expenses in different CRUD-modules or lists in the frontend, do some filtering up there or in the server controller.

Comment: To get them in parallel you can use `async` library and run your request in parallel collecting results afterwards

Comment: It probably would, but also heed this. IMHO and that of various people who even worked to create the term "middleware", you are doing this in the wrong place. "Middleware" should really deal with the response from the server in the main "application" that you are writing. It should have no concept, nor access to anything relating to "model" data. That is the realm of your application. The only exceptions are "general model", being configured from such sources as session storage and authentication/authorization. Please keep application logic in your application as a best principle.